# FirstData - Bad Request (22) - Invalid Credit Card Number

Tags: firstdata

We have used globalgatewaye4 sandbox on our website. It was working fine with old gateway credentials. Yesterday, we have created new gateway credentials and use that in one. After that we got below error response:

```
FirstData Object
(
    [username:protected] => RC1416-71
    [password:protected] => 7aXbWGpmgEDUkd6AarMOWmmkN5ljsij8
    [transactionType:protected] => 00
    [errorCode:protected] => 22
    [errorMessage:protected] => Invalid Credit Card Number
    [response:protected] => Bad Request (22) - Invalid Credit Card Number
    [headers:protected] => Array
    (
        [url] => https://api.demo.globalgatewaye4.firstdata.com/transaction/v11
        [content_type] => application/json; charset=utf-8
        [http_code] => 400
        [header_size] => 547
        [request_size] => 430
        [filetime] => -1
        [ssl_verify_result] => 0
        [redirect_count] => 0
        [total_time] => 1.842809
        [namelookup_time] => 4.9E-5
        [connect_time] => 0.316445
        [pretransfer_time] => 1.205292
        [size_upload] => 233
        [size_download] => 45
        [speed_download] => 24
        [speed_upload] => 126
        [download_content_length] => -1
        [upload_content_length] => 233
        [starttransfer_time] => 1.842732
        [redirect_time] => 0
        [redirect_url] => 
        [primary_ip] => 52.89.17.115
        [certinfo] => Array
            (
            )

        [primary_port] => 443
        [local_ip] => 192.168.225.234
        [local_port] => 57178
    )

    [arrayResponse:protected] => 
    [postFields:protected] => Array
    (
    )

    [apiVersion:protected] => v11
)
```

We have checked the gateway dashboard transaction page card type showing "Pre-Authorization" but in my application, we got above message. Please help and let us know is there any configuration change?

Comment: Not knowing anything about firstdata, my guess would be to follow the error message it gave you. It says you have an invalid credit card number.

Comment: my blind guess is you are missing their dev doc guideline. May be you have to pass encrypted number or something